# How to hide table rows if Id = id

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table here that I am trying to hide table row if the patient ID = patient ID. The table is loaded dynamically with XML. I will provide an example here.

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Patient ID</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Reason for visit</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Christian</td>
            <td>Cold</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Christian</td>
            <td>Checkup</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Suzy</td>
            <td>Cold</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Cold</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Blood Test</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Mary</td>
            <td>Ankle</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>Alex</td>
            <td>Cold</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So the rows where id = 1 and where id = 3 both have multiple rows. I want to only display one row and hide the other 3 unless i double click the row then it will display the 2,3,4,5 rows etc.

so this will be the end result:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Patient ID</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Reason for visit</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Christian</td>
            <td>Cold</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Suzy</td>
            <td>Cold</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Cold</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Mary</td>
            <td>Ankle</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>Alex</td>
            <td>Cold</td>
        </tr>


    </tbody>
</table>
```

and when you double click the row it will switch the css to display the hidden rows.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I have only been able to toggle the css class of .hide (display: none) but have not been able to group the tr dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use JavaScript to iterate over all rows in the table. If any have the
   same ID as a previous row then set the style to `display: 'none'`.
2. Add an event listener to each row that listens for double clicks. On a double click check the row's next sibling. If it has the same ID as the current row then set its style to `display:'table-cell'`.

```js
    var ids = [],
        rows = document.querySelectorAll( '.table tr' )

    Array.from( rows ).forEach( row => {
        var rowID = row.querySelector( 'td:first-child' ).innerHTML
        if ( !ids.includes( rowID ) )
            ids.push( rowID )
        else
            row.style.display = 'none'

        row.addEventListener( 'dblclick', () => {
            var next = row.nextElementSibling,
                nextID = ( next ? next.querySelector( 'td:first-child' ).innerHTML : null )
            if ( nextID = rowID )
                next.style.display = 'table-row'
        } );
    } )
```

```html
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Patient ID</td>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Reason for visit</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Christian</td>
                <td>Cold</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Christian</td>
                <td>Checkup</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Suzy</td>
                <td>Cold</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>John</td>
                <td>Cold</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>John</td>
                <td>Blood Test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>Mary</td>
                <td>Ankle</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>Alex</td>
                <td>Cold</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```